# Why does type& cannot bind const lvalue

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

Why does type& cannot bind to a const L-value? I understand type& can bind to L-value but is const L-value is just an immutable address of some type of variable? My 2nd question is why does type& cannot bind to a "mordifiable R-value" either? your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show some code. It sounds like you're asking why a const can't be referenced by a non-const.

Comment: Please fix the broken english. I suspect there might then be a clear question in there. But currently, I cannot decipher it.

Comment: You're violating const-correectness if you do.  You cannot alias a const name with a non const name. Simple as that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: @NathanOliver, thanks.

Comment: @Jesper, I am pretty sure my question here is cleared and got answered.

Comment: @joechang well, then all is well.

Comment: @Jesper, as always, your right etiquette is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is type& cannot bind to const L-value?

If it were allowed, you will be able to modify a `const` object.

```
void foo(int& v)
{
   v = 10;
}

int main()
{
   const int i = 20;
   int& ref = i;
   foo(ref);  // If the previous line were allowed, the value of i will be 10 after
              // the function returns, which violates the const-ness of i
}
```